# How to get OLD VALUE and NEW VALUE from dynamically get column name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
SET @total_no_of_columns :=  (select count(*) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS c where c.TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName' and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TableSchema');

SET @iCNT = 1;

     WHILE @iCNT<=  @total_no_of_columns DO
             SET @col_name := (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TableSchema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName' AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @iCNT);

              IF  OLD.@col_name <> NEW.@col_name THEN  
                    //Query to insert in audit table
            END IF; 

             SET @iCNT = @iCNT + 1;
     END WHILE;
```

But `OLD.@col_name <> NEW.@col_name` is wrong.
 What should be the solution?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger

In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used.

In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated.

In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no new row.

But the OLD and New is used on the columns which are already present.But you use on variables its impossible.still If you want store that values in a variable and then you can use it

Comment: Thanks Ajay. IT is an AFTER UPDATE trigger

Comment: No friend. You can see the conversation between me and Ravinder for better understanding of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to buffer current column name as previous column name once it is read. On next iteration compare it with newly read column name.

Change your code as shown below:

```
select count(*) INTO @total_no_of_columns 
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS c 
 where c.TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName' 
   and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TableSchema';

SET @iCNT = 1;
SET @previous_column_name := '';

WHILE @iCNT<=  @total_no_of_columns DO
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME INTO @current_column_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TableSchema' 
     AND TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName' 
     AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @iCNT;

  IF @previous_column_name <> current_column_name THEN
    -- Query to insert in audit table

    -- lastly set current name to previous name
    @previous_column_name := @current_column_name;
  END IF; 

  SET @iCNT = @iCNT + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinder. But I want to compare between the OLD value and NEW value. Suppose in MyTable there are 4 columns such as col1,col2,col3,col4. I want to insert into audit table if any column's value has been changed. I need to store the column name also. Can you please help me? This is an AFTER UPDATE trigger.

Comment: Can you show table structure on which trigger is defined?

Comment: Table Name : MyTable

Columns are:

col1 : INTEGER : Primary Key
col2 : VARCHAR(45)
COL3 : DATETIME
COL4 : VARCHAR(10)

Comment: Not just table name. Post output of `desc MyTable`.